# Disabling inactive toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I have the following functional code. However, I would like to know how I can disable toggle buttons. I always want to have one of my bottom navbar icons active and its respective content should be shown in the main section. If I click on the active navbar icon (the toggle) it wouldn't be deactivated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // only show menu-1
  $('.menu-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-2, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-1').toggleClass('active');
    $('.content-1').toggleClass('active'); 
  });

  // only show menu-2
    $('.menu-2').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-1, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-1, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-1, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-2').toggleClass('active');
    $('.content-2').toggleClass('active'); 
  });

  // only show menu-3
    $('.menu-3').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-1').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-1').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-2, .content-1').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-3').toggleClass('active');
    $('.content-3').toggleClass('active'); 
  });

});
```

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 90vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  position: relative;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bottom-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-grey-dark-3);
  z-index: 50;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

      > a {
      display: block;
      color: green;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 0 10px;

      &.active {
        color: black;
      }
    }
}

.menu-1.active,
.menu-2.active,
.menu-3.active {
  color: black;
}

.content-1,
.content-2,
.content-3 {
  display: none;
}

.content-1.active,
.content-2.active,
.content-3.active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <header>My header</header>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-1">House content</div>
    <div class="content-2">Map content</div>
    <div class="content-3">Explore content</div>
  <div class="bottom-navbar">
    <a href="#" class="menu-1"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-2"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-3"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you find it easier, here's my **CodePen**: https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/vYYaRzN

Comment: Based on your example above, you could either set whatever elements you wanted to be active right after your `document.ready` call.  `$('.menu1').toggleClass('active');` `$('.content-1').toggleClass('active');`

Or you could simulate a button click if that is better. [jQuery event trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggleClass() you could use addClass():
https://codepen.io/vladanme/pen/LYYBrqJ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // only show menu-1
  $('.menu-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-2, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-1').addClass('active');
    $('.content-1').addClass('active'); 
  });

  // only show menu-2
    $('.menu-2').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-1, .menu-3').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-1, .menu-3').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-1, .content-3').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-2').addClass('active');
    $('.content-2').addClass('active'); 
  });

  // only show menu-3
    $('.menu-3').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu-2, .menu-1').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.menu-2, .menu-1').removeClass('active');
            $('.content-2, .content-1').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.menu-3').addClass('active');
    $('.content-3').addClass('active'); 
  });





});
```

Comment: how could I make menu-1 the one being active by default? Here before clicking in any button, the default is nothing. By simply displaying menu-1 the content overlaps.

Comment: I updated codepen to make menu-1 as default. You basically need to add active class in the HTML for those elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jQuery code. Anyone can enhance that.

```
       $(document).ready(function() {



$('.bottom-navbar a').click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('class');
    var lastchr = cls.substr(cls.length - 1);
    $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("div[class^='content-'],div[class*=' content-']").removeClass('active');
    $('.content-'+ lastchr).addClass('active');
   })  


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addClass()` instead of `toggleClass()`.

It looks like you have the code to clear the inactive buttons already. So you're only left with the button that you would like to maintain active.

```
[..]
$('.menu-1').addClass('active');
$('.content-1').addClass('active');
[..]

[..]
$('.menu-2').addClass('active');
$('.content-2').addClass('active'); 
[..]

[..]
$('.menu-3').addClass('active');
$('.content-3').addClass('active'); 
[..]
```